# Count results in 2 mysql column

Tags: mysql, count

I need to count how many times a result is found in 2 mysql column.

Ex.

```
|  Column A   |  Column B   |
|   white     |    black    |
|   black     |    green    |
|   orange    |    white    |
|   black     |    blue     |
```

I need to get this result:

```
white -> 2 times
black -> 3 times
green -> 1 time
orange -> 1 time
blue -> 1 time
```

I did it for single column and it works:

```
SELECT 
    column_name
    , COUNT(column_name) as total 
FROM table_name 
WHERE (......) 
GROUP BY column_name 
HAVING column_name != '' 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

I can't understand how it can works with 2 columns

Answer (score 2):

For your particular use, I would do something like this:

```
SELECT col, COUNT(col) FROM
    (SELECT columnA as col FROM table
       UNION ALL SELECT columnB FROM table) as tmp_table
WHERE ... GROUP BY ... HAVING ... ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: you beat me to it, good answer - I would do it a bit different - see my answer as well

Answer (score 2):

Try it with a `UNION ALL` clause, selecting all which you need in the inner query (meaning, keep the `WHERE` clause in the nested query)

```
SELECT
    column_nameA
    ,count(*) AS total
FROM(
    SELECT 
        column_nameA
    FROM table_name 
    WHERE (......) 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
        column_nameb
    FROM table_name 
    WHERE (......) 
)a 
GROUP BY column_nameA
HAVING column_name != '' 
ORDER BY 1
```